# If a method is started with invoke, Exceptions do not cause a crash

Tags: java, exception, reflection, runtimeexception

For some reason, if an method is called via `invoke()`, uncaught exceptions it throws do not cause a crash. However, it does exit the method. Does `invoke` run it another thread (because exceptions just crash the thread, right?), and if so is there a way to send the exception up or something?

Here is a simple example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("Main").getMethod("thrower").invoke(null);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {}
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {}
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) {}
        catch (SecurityException e) {}
    }
    public static void thrower() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's never a good idea to have an empty `catch` body, let alone _6_ of them.

Comment: @rgettman That was just an example of the issue.

Comment: *"That was just an example of the issue"* - Actually, it was the **cause** of the issue.  Which reinforces rgettman's advice.  Don't do it.  Not even in "examples".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`java.lang.reflect.Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) docs:

> @exception [`InvocationTargetException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html) if the underlying method throws an exception.

You are catching an [`InvocationTargetException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html), it will be thrown with a [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) cause:

```
catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    final Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    // cause.getClass().getName() = java.lang.RuntimeException
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not run in separate Thread. The `RuntimeException` thrown from `thrower` is actually getting wrapped by `InvocationTargetException` during reflection call and is later catched by your code that does nothing.

See Javadoc for [InvocationTargetException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html)

> InvocationTargetException is a checked exception **that wraps an
>   exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor**. As of release
>   1.4, this exception has been retrofitted to conform to the general purpose exception-chaining mechanism. The "target exception" that is
>   provided at construction time and accessed via the
>   getTargetException() method is now known as the cause, and may be
>   accessed via the Throwable.getCause() method, as well as the
>   aforementioned "legacy method."